# Efficient ways of removing duplicate from a queryset?

Tags: django

I have a table called Clue which has a foreignkey relation with another entity called Entry.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entry_text = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    .....
class Clue(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ......
```

Now, let's say I have the following queryset

```
clues = Clue.objects.filter(clue_text=clue.clue_text)
```

which returns something like this-

```
 [<Clue: ATREST-Still>, <Clue: ATREST-Still>, <Clue: ATREST-Still>, <Clue: YET-Still>, <Clue: YET-Still>, <Clue: SILENT-Still>]
```

As, you can see there are different clue objects but some of them are tied to the same entry objects.
I tried the following:-

```
 clues = Clue.objects.filter(clue_text=clue.clue_text).distinct()
But this won't work as the field repeating is a foreign key value. Correct me if I am wrong.
```

Essentially, I want my queryset to look something like this

```
   [<Clue: ATREST-Still>, <Clue: YET-Still>, <Clue: SILENT-Still>]
```

I was able to achieve it through the following but I was looking at a solution that can be done at the database level rather than doing it in memory.
This is my approach

```
clue_objs=[]
 temp = {}
 clues = Clue.objects.filter(clue_text=clue.clue_text)
    for clue in clues:
        if not temp.get(clue.entry.entry_text):
            temp[clue.entry.entry_text]=1
            clue_objs.append(clue)
```

Comment: This looks more like a data model problem. You should make something like a `ClueText` model and then use two `ForeignKey`s in your `Clue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `.distinct()` on the `QuerySet` you obtain with [**`.values_list(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), so something like:

```
clues = Clue.objects.filter(
    clue_text=clue.clue_text
).values_list('clue_text', flat=True).distinct()
```

But this looks more like a modeling problem: if you have a lot of duplicated data, that often means you should construct a new model that stores that data only once, and then reference that model with a relation (like a `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField` or `ManyToManyField`).